# How to separate a byte from a byte stream

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte

I merged the bytes of a `string` and the byte of the length of that `string`
Ex. `stackoverflow13`(readable presentation of the byte of `stackoverflow` plus the bytes of the length`13`) now this combined bytes will be sent to another program that uses `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byte, index, count)` I want to separate the index of `stackoverflow` and `13` for the `count`. How can I do that. This is the code:

```
Dim text1() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("stackoverflow")
        Dim len1() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(text1.Length)
        Dim byteLen As Integer = text1.Length + len1.Length
        Dim bStream(byteLen) As Byte
        text1.CopyTo(bStream, 0)
        len1.CopyTo(bStream, text1.Length)
        '                           |
        '                           | Byte stream "bStream"
        '                           V
        '-----------------------------------------------------------
        '--------------------Different program---------------------- 
        '-----------------------------------------------------------
        '                           |
        '                           | Byte stream "bStream"
        '                           |
        '                           |                       | n = supposed to be len1
        '                           V                       V     from the stream
        Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bStream, 0, n))
```

How can I do this multiple timea on the similar stream? Ex.

`fileOne,fileOneLength,fileTwo,fileTwoLength...`

Comment: Why do you need to send the string length?

Comment: Your question is misleading since you aren't sending "stackoverflow13". You are converting an integer into 4 byte. The last 4 byte of your stream will be the integer for the length. Usually this is send at the beginning as a packet header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use a delimiter to tell the other program where to start looking for the length data such as "-" so it would be "stackloverflow-13".

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Parsing using a  delimeter 
    Dim text1() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("stackoverflow" & "-") ' concatenate a delimter in the string
    '   Convert to string, otherwise the program sends the byte value of 13 plus 3 padded zeros so you end up transmitting a Carriage return and 3 null characters
    Dim len1() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text1.Length - 1.ToString) ' Subtract the delimteter character value from the total
    Dim byteLen As Integer = text1.Length + len1.Length
    Dim bStream(byteLen) As Byte
    text1.CopyTo(bStream, 0)
    len1.CopyTo(bStream, text1.Length)


    ' This goes in the other program 
    Dim Str() As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bStream, 0, bStream.Length).Split("-")

    Dim Text As String = Str(0)
    Dim Index As Integer = CInt(Str(1))


End Sub
```